# Got a strange error after trying to recompile FNF's exe source

Tags: haxe

For some reason while trying to recompile the game's source code like I usually do it ended up showing me this error message that I can't find a solution to online

```
Called from ? line 1
Called from CommandLineTools.hx line 1895`
Called from CommandLineTools.hx line 22
Called from a C function
Called from CommandLineTools.hx line 125
Called from CommandLineTools.hx line 1703
Called from lime/tools/ProjectXMLParser.hx line 21
Called from a C function
Called from lime/tools/ProjectXMLParser.hx line 50
Called from lime/tools/ProjectXMLParser.hx line 2043
Called from lime/tools/ProjectXMLParser.hx line 1528
Called from lime/tools/ProjectXMLParser.hx line 608
Called from a C function
Called from lime/tools/ProjectXMLParser.hx line 719
Called from a C function
Called from lime/tools/ProjectXMLParser.hx line 709
Called from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/haxe/4.2.1/x64/std/neko/_std/sys/FileSystem.hx line 69
Called from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/haxe/4.2.1/x64/std/neko/_std/sys/FileSystem.hx line 60
Uncaught exception - std@sys_file_type
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is causing this compilation error?

Comment: The error comes from a `sys.FileSystem.isDirectory()` call, most likely due to the file/directory in question being missing. CommandLineTools.hx is from `lime`. Adding a trace() call at the quoted line should help figure out what is it that's missing

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem on a file name included in an asset directory (that just happened to me). Check if one of your images or other asset has any special character. I guess the lime command tool has difficulties with some characters.